# Maven appears to be ignoring source and target in webapp

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm getting "Generated servlet error:|try-with-resources is not supported in -source 1.5".  1.5 is maven's default according to another question on the topic, but I thought I had fixed that in my pom.xml -

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.sspo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sspo-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>website</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>website</name>

  <properties>
    <jetty.version>9.0.5.v20130815</jetty.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sspso</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.sspo.package1</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sspo</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.sspo.package2</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Other packages in the project work fine with 1.7, as seen in the parent pom -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sspo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sspo-parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>sspo-parent</name>  

  <modules>
    <module>try-with-resources-works-here</module>
    <module>and-here</module>
    <module>even-in-this-one</module>
    <module>website</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Ultimately, I think the question is probably "what have I done wrong that maven is ignoring the source and target specifications?"  There are similar questions out there, but the ones I've seen are either not solved or suggest things that exist in my pom.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty is using 1.5 source and target args by default for JSP compilation.  See [Jetty embedded and JSP compilation to 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152741/jetty-embedded-and-jsp-compilation-to-1-7) for pointers and info on switching Jetty to use 1.7

Comment: To anybody coming here, those links took me to the method I went with that worked once I got rid of some XML typos from the examples.  I specified a servlet of org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet in the web.xml, mapped it to *.jsp, and set its compilerSourceVM and compilerTargetVM to 1.7.